# How can i print the Hydrated Storage Data stored in device?

Tags: flutter, bloc

How can I print the data stored in Hydrated Bloc Flutter? How can I print the Hydrated Storage Data stored in the device ? I am facing this problem from long term.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
  runApp(NewWidget());

  print(HydratedBloc.storage);
}
```